# How to add an item to a scrollview from another activity?

Tags: android

I want to add an item to a Scrollview that is present in a different activity from a second activity. Say I have a button in my second activity and when this button is clicked I want to add an item to the ScrollView present in a different activity. My ScrollView row consists of two TextViews and a button. The problem is that each button in the Scrollview is used for a different url. How can I add these urls to these buttons at runtime. Can anybody suggest a work around for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollView activity will be created AFTER you click the AddItem button a few times. So just save the "added data" to a class that both Activities can access. When ScrollView activity launches, load the current data. Even if you're keeping the ScrollView open in the background, onResume will still be called, and you can load the current data there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You can Transfer Data from one activity to another Through Intent:

### First Activity From Which To send

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, 
SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

### Second Activity

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

Yeah.. That Should Do it... Its pretty easy and neat... Hope I helped...